# $_POST Array Values from HTTP Request

Tags: php, ios, arrays, swift

I have an application (iOS) written in swift that makes an http post request to a PHP script. I want to pass an array from swift to the PHP API. Swift arrays are formatted as follows:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and PHP arrays are obviously formatted like this:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

However, when I try to call

```
$_POST['arrayFromSwift'];
```

I can't access indexes of individual items. How can I parse the array (either in swift or in the PHP API so that I can access individual items?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `$_POST['arrayFromSwift']`? Do a `var_dump($_POST['arrayFromSwift']);`.

Comment: If you Stringify that array you should be able to make something out of it with `json_decode()` in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your values are coming into the php page like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Then you could use php's explode function

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

like this:

```
$val = $_POST['arrayFromSwift']);
// Cut off the end brackets and separate by comma
$array = explode(",", substr($val, 1, -1));
```

EDIT:

The reason you have to manually parse it is because PHP receives the POST data as a raw string which you must manually convert to a PHP array in order to use it in PHP as an array object.

Comment: It should still be passed as an array rather than a string(hopefully at least).

Comment: @ViperCode PHP Receives the data as a string coming from the raw socket, you have to interpret the value as an array yourself. (just like parsing json requests)

Comment: Ah gotcha! Should add that to your answer for future reference. Completely skipped my mind.

Comment: This works! thanks! Would this still work if the swift array included quotes around the items?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'work', it would do the samething only each value in the array would contain the quotes as well. You would have to run a str_replace() on the string first to remove the quotes like so `str_replace('"', "", $val);
str_replace("'", "", $val);` But to warn you, that will remove every quote in the string, so if you had the string: "I haven't seen it" then the single quote in haven't would also be removed, so it's all how you choose to format it